# Trigger script on React hot refresh or after file creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to add some code generation for my current project, and to implement this I want to trigger a node script after each change, right before React does recompile and hot reloading, so this script can check if certain files have been changed and generate output, so React can recompile taking this output into consideration.

My question is this possible? and if yes, how can I implement it?

For example i already have file

```
export default class A extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    this.name = "A"          
  }    
}
```

and I have generated file

```
export default class Generated {
  getComponent(name){
     if(name==="A") return new A();
  }
}
```

now i add file

```
export default class B extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    this.name = "B"          
  }    
}
```

And i want to trigger my codegeneration script, so it will alter Generated class like this:

```
export default class Generated {
  getComponent(name){
     if(name==="A") return new A();
     else if(name==="B") return new B();
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar), with this library you can set a watcher for certain path, and it will invoke a listener for the event that you set, e.g.

```js
chokidar.watch(YOUR_PATH, OPTIONAL_OPTIONS)
.on('add', YOUR_LISTENER)
.on('change', YOUR_LISTENER)
.on('unlink', YOUR_LISTENER)
```

I hope that it works for you!

Comment: hey man, thank you! this is exactly what I`ve looked for! 
I already thought about using TypeScript compiler API or ejecting, but this did not came into my mind for some reason.Thank you

Comment: It was a pleasure!